# mongodb aggregate, toArrary is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregate

```
getCartProducts:(userId) => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            let cartItems=await db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).aggregate([
                {
                    $match:{user:ObjectId(userId)}
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from:collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION,
                        let:{prodList:'$products'},
                        pipeline:[
                            {
                                $match:{
                                    $expr:{
                                        $in:['$_id',"$$prodList"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        as:'cartItems'
                    }
                }
            ]).toArray()
            console.log(cartItems);
            resolve(cartItems)
        })
    }
```

```
router.get('/cart',async(req,res,next)=>{
  if(req.session.user)
  {
    let products=await userHelpers.getCartProducts(req.session.user._id)
    console.log(products);
    res.render('user/cart', { pageUser:true,uname})
  }
  else
  {
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
})
```

I'm tried to make cart for each user using mongodb. and used aggregate function, and finally used toArray() function, but the array is undefined. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.10/classes/AggregationCursor.html#toArray) `.toArray()` returns a promise. But are you sure your query is correct and that it matches any documents?

Comment: Is it really `undefined`, or is it empty? Also, useless use of `new Promise`.